# Вызов submit из нового окна

Tags: javascript

В заполненной форме при нажатии на кнопку создается окно предварительной проверки введенных данных:

```
<input type="button" name="send" value="Проверка" onclick="opWind(form)">`
```

Как из созданного окна вызвать submit() для формы главного окна. Такая кнопка не реагирует:

```
win1.document.write("\<input type='button' value='Отправить' onclick='form.submit()'> <input type='button' value='Закрыть' onclick='self.close()'>");
```

Comment: ЕМНИП не win1, а parent -- обратиться к родительскому окну, Это раз. Второе, а зачем вы ПИШЕТЕ в win1?

Comment: В начале же написано "создается окно предварительной проверки введенных данных".

Comment: новое окно: win1 = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=300,height=50,resizable=0,scrollbars=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0");

Comment: а, да, сорри)

ну все равно, из созданного окна к родительскому обратиться через javascript parent.<найти-форму-по-атрибуту>.submit()

Comment: parent.document.feedback.submit(); проверил parent произвольно добавив эту строку в новом окне..как и предполагалось при создании окна срабатывает submit.
Вставляю эту же строку в onclick..ноль реакции =\

Comment: ошибки какие-то в консоли? или просто тишина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В новом окне parent будет равен self. Нужно обращаться к объекту opener.

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, поменял parent на opener, всё заработало, спасибо =)